# How to create a redirect in HTACCESS for this subdomain with dynamic urls?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

How can I redirect the sub-domain that has a bunch of dynamic urls?

Example:

```
http://**ca**.*main*.com/blogs?&blogPage=8&blogPage=3&blogPage=3&blogPage=1&blogPage=6
```

The other urls are similar, except has a different page and blog number etc.

Basically, I want to redirect anything from the "ca" subdomain that has /blog?

Thanks
JR

Comment: Hi all,Any help here?  Thanks.

Comment: I has asked where do you want these URLs to be redirected to?

Comment: Hi I would like to be redirected to the main www.main.com but without the /blog?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as first rule in **root `.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} blogPage=\d+
RewriteRule ^blogs(/.*)?$ http://www.main.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: by /blog/ are you referring to a blog subfolder?  If yes, we don't have a subfolder, we only have a subdomain.